# Image slide in/out from left with time on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-ads-api

Actually i am trying to create Animated Banner Ads, same like this...

https://adwords.google.com/aw_displayads/creatives/ExternalPreview?hl=en_US&ad=216127501651&adGroup=50971776412&ocid=141653320&isObfuscatedOcid=false&showMulPreview=true&showVariations=true&creativeType=19&pk=null&sig=ACiVB_ywiD3ua55vbxNzKFKx8nZYtGWJPw

Please guide me how to do this, i have PSDs and need to convert them in Animated Banner Ads HTML.
and also make sure the ads are google adwords compliant and have a working link.

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Comment: Its working @George Daniel

Comment: Try logging out and see if that link works for you. Or try another browser. It doesn't work.

Comment: no need to login for this URL, i also checked in different browser and Incognito. Its working.

Comment: @Georage why downvote?  :(  Link is working for me in all browsers.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I don't downvote. Link is just not working for me. I tried it everywhere, as well.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to bring up the page. Most likely you got downvoted because of the vagueness in your "question."

I'm not sure if there are any guides on this particular topic, but I'll let you know how you create a similar effect.

Let's first discuss the elements on the page.

- A picture
- Some text, "Your social work..."
- Learn more button
- Blue boxes coming in from the left/right

Not many objects in here. Most likely they are all contained in a single div. In that div, we can assume there is the following:

- Background image
- 6 child Divs for the blue boxes
- Another child div for the text "your social work..."
- Another child div for the "learn more" button (which is not really a button)

The whole div itself is a link, so that's pretty easy. This should take about 5 minutes to replicate, but here is the overall structure we're looking at:

```
<a href="www.somelink.com">
    <div>
        <div></div> // 6 blue boxes
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>

        <div><p>Your social work...</p></div> // text

        <div>Learn More</div> // Fake button
    </div>
</a>
```

Essentially, this is your HTML structure. You can just add transitions/animations to the child elements to gain the effect you see there on the example page you have. You would use transition-delays and animation-delays.

Comment: I am just looking for animation same like with given URL.. This is my structure... <html><body>
<style>body{margin: 0px;}
.main_ads{width: 120px; height: 600px; background-image: url(images/background-img1.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; }</style>
<div class="main_ads">
<img id="inner-one" src="images/inner1.png" alt="">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$('.main_ads').click(function(){
$('#inner-one').slideToggle(400);});
});</script></body></html>

Comment: Use the shortcut Ctrl+K on the code to format it.